# catalina.out replaced with old log

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat7, catalina.out

I have tomcat 7 running on my server. accidentally my catalina.out replaced with an old log(catalina.out before 7 days). Log is not printing on current catalina.out because it is an old one. Is there anyway to rollback this situation or create a catalina.out without restarting the server?

Comment: no, you need to restart

Comment: Thank you Vorsprung.. So it seems restarting is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts and writes to it. But in your case, since `catalina.out` was replaced while `tomcat` was running it is holding up the original `catalina.out` file reference and writing to the deleted file. The reason why it is logging into your old catalina.out file.

You can get rid of this by restarting the `tomcat` server.

Since you have replaced the new catalina.out with old catalina.out it is impossible to rollback. Going forward try to use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
info on this.